# How to hide a ribbon tab?

Tags: feature, editing-menu

I would like to remove a custom tab on the ribbon.  Is this possible with HideCustomAction?

I have attempted using HideCustomAction with the location and HideActionId set for the desired tab to be removed but it doesn't appear to be working.  I see lots of samples for hiding groups or buttons but not the entire tab.

The tab that I would like to hide is one that is shown for document libraries (like the Library tab)

The solution for me was the following

```
<CustomAction
Id="RemoveRibbon"
Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView"
RegistrationId="101"
RegistrationType="List">
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.CustomTab1"></CommandUIDefinition>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.CustomTab1.CustomGroup1.UpdateFolders"></CommandUIDefinition>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.CustomTab1.CustomGroup1.Update2Folders"></CommandUIDefinition>        
  </CommandUIDefinitions>     
</CommandUIExtension>
```

The caml above specified the location of the ribbon 'CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView', the id of the tab 'Ribbon.CustomTab1' then the id's for each button that was in the tab i.e. 'Ribbon.CustomTab1.CustomGroup1.UpdateFolders' and 'Ribbon.CustomTab1.CustomGroup1.Update2Folders'  (they are specified as id's in the custom action that put them on the ribbon but here they are the location property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's possible but not with HideCustomAction. You can do this with a CustomAction.
Take a look at: [Hiding a Tab Group from a custom list type in SharePoint 2010′s Ribbon](http://www.novolocus.com/2011/01/07/hiding-a-tab-group-from-a-custom-list-type-in-sharepoint-2010s-ribbon/)

Comment: +1, and thanks for your input, I can attest that the article link is correct. But it would better to add a particular CAML code example right here, even if it is just a copy-paste from the article. It believed to be a good practice. For details, please have a look at this meta discussion: http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117/links-in-answers

Comment: The solution for me was the following

Comment: Edit this answer so i can mark it + and correct